# list view isn't populating

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help here. I'm trying to populate a listview from a json response.  the response is posting, for some reason it isn't showing the list?  anything helps
Also it is stopping on the list view, just not seeing anything.

```
extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ideasList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://theideavault.no-ip.org//android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "ideas";
private static final String TAG_IID = "iid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "idea";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray ideas = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_idea);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ideasList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String iid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.iid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditIdeaActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_IID, iid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllIdeasActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Reteiving Ideas from database. Wooooooo...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Ideas: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                ideas = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < ideas.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = ideas.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String iid = c.getString(TAG_IID);
                    String idea = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_IID, iid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, idea);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    ideasList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewIdeaActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllIdeasActivity.this, ideasList,
                        R.layout.list_idea, new String[] { TAG_IID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.iid, R.id.idea });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}}
```

Comment: are you getting any error? and no need to use runOnUiThread in onPostExecute because this method always run on UI Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great mistake you did is while initialize TAG_PRODUCTS variable.

**Mistake:**

private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "ideas";

**Correct value:**

private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";

BTW, are you fetching ideas or products? because your response is of products and your code describes Idea :)

Comment: ok truth is im converting some code for my purpose.  yes i was pointing at the wrong thing.  got that figured out. im now getting the right json back.  It is actully now showing the list view, just only pulling one value at a time?